# Running SSH through system suspension

Tags: suspend, .desktop, openssh

I would like to have my system suspend automatically when I'm not using it. However, I would still like to be able to remote into my machine any time I need.

I keep OpenSSH-server and my Desktop running all the time, so when I'm at school I can quickly SSH into my stuff any time.

The thing is, it wastes power, and I'm pretty sure it wears out the life out of my CPU (getting heated, I'm pretty sure), and hard drives (since they're spinning).

Now, I've noticed that some OS's actually enter (their version of) suspension, and wait for a keyboard/mouse event before they com back to life. I assume that the computer is still making computations, but is severely underclocked, producing as little heat as possible, with no hard drives or fans spinning, and all monitors turned off.

If the computer still has its RAM and CPU turned on, I would think it is possible to load the SSH server onto the RAM and slowly, consistently process the code to check if there's any packets it received.

What I would like is to be able to suspend my system, then be able to use SSH to remote into the system and wake it up remotely if I needed to.

I'm just not sure if OpenSSH server is still active and listening when I suspend my system, or if I would need to do something custom, or a setting, or something.

Comment: please check http://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan